# Sum record between two dates for different users in mysql query Issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have two tables `lead` and `lead_details`. There is a field `status`. If `status=1` is open, `status=2` is close and `status=3` is not specified.

I want to find sum of all Open,close and not specified for each user/agent.
Here is what I tried but it give me wrong data

```
select agent_id,
       type,
       status,
       created_date,
       category_id,
       sum(case when status = 2 then val else 0 end) as closed1,
       sum(case when status = 1 then val else 0 end) as opened1, 
       sum(case when status = 3 then val else 0 end) as notspecefied1 
  from ( select l.agent_id,
                l.type,
                ld.category_id,
                l.status,
                l.created_date,
                count(*) as val 
           from crm_leads l,
                crm_leads_details ld 
          where l.id=ld.lead_id AND  
                status in (2, 1, 3) 
          GROUP BY status, agent_id 
        ) t 
 WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2013-8-2' AND '2013-9-2' 
 GROUP BY agent_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `WHERE created_date` clause in the subquery.

```
select agent_id,type,status,created_date,category_id,
       sum(case when status = 2 then val else 0 end) as closed1,
       sum(case when status = 1 then val else 0 end) as opened1, 
       sum(case when status = 3 then val else 0 end) as notspecefied1 
from ( select l.agent_id,l.type,ld.category_id,l.status,l.created_date,
       count(*) as val from crm_leads l JOIN crm_leads_details ld 
       ON l.id=ld.lead_id 
       WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2013-8-2' AND '2013-9-2' AND status in (2, 1, 3)
       GROUP BY status, agent_id ) t 
GROUP BY agent_id
```

Note that the `created_date` in the result will just be a randomly selected date in the period for each agent.